# How to solve failed connection to service?

Tags: android

I want to get to the service in specific URL .... I use retrofit to get it but it give me an error connection to the URL...while the URL is active in chrome.

in the code I write ??? instead to correct one ^__^  (this code is class APIClient)
and to be sure that I work in correct way I was built an api in mocky site with the same json file .... and it is work 
so can any one help me please

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://111.222.1.12:0000/???/???/????/";

//database
public static final String BASE_URL2 = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/";

public static Boolean URL=true;
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if (retrofit==null) {
        if(URL)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        else
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL2)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try using my ApiClient, I'm using rxJava so you need to redesign the APIClient to your need

```
public class ApiClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 120;
private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;


public static Retrofit getClient(Context context) {

    if (okHttpClient == null)
        initOkHttp(context);

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_PATH)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

private static void initOkHttp(Context context) {
    ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Request-Type", "Android")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });


    okHttpClient = httpClient.build();
}

public static void resetApiClient() {
    retrofit = null;
    okHttpClient = null;
}
}
```

Hope this reference can help you solve your problems

Comment: thanks JEFE ... but the problem was I send an object to the server and it didn't understand that cus the input to the service was 5 parameters and I passed these parameters as an object.

Comment: rather than you pass it by object why not pass it by string it's easier to handle and just put some delimiter before you pass the value, then in your server just split it by your delimiter then you can get your value from post or get method